# Cannot add GWT event handler

Tags: java, gwt

There is a problem with my code where GWT event handlers are not fired after Panel is appended to a DIV

```
final FormPanel form = new FormPanel();
VerticalPanel panel = new VerticalPanel();
// Other code omitted for simplicity

DOM.getElementById("modal_panel").appendChild(panel.getElement());

// Submit button
panel.add(new Button("Submit", new ClickHandler() {
 public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
  GWT.log("Submit clicked");
  form.submit();
 }
}));
```

When the submit button is clicked it should do the form submit action, but it even doesn't show the GWT log on the DevMode console. What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a good idea to add a widget directly in the DOM. GWT does a lot of things, when adding a widget. Adding elements by hand to the DOM will cause some problems. One of the problem is, that the events are not sinked and handlers will not work.

Try something like this:

```
DOM.sinkEvent(panel.getElement(), Event.ONCLICK);
```

after adding the panel.

If you want to add your panel to an existing HTML page, try:

```
RootPanel.get("modal_panel").add(panel);
```